# How do I find out what version of SQL Server for Linux I have?

Tags: sql-server, linux, ubuntu

How do I find out what version of SQL I am running if I can't connect to it because it's crashing? Is there something like `--version`

```
$ ./sqlservr --version
Dump collecting thread [8633] hit exception [6]. Exiting.
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

## Using dpkg

```
dpkg -l | grep -i mssql-server
ii  mssql-server                              14.0.3008.27-1                              amd64        Microsoft SQL Server Relational Database Engine
```

## Using `PAL_PROGRAM_INFO=1`

You can set the undocumented environmental variable `PAL_PROGRAM_INFO` for a lot of information,

```
PAL_PROGRAM_INFO=1 ./sqlservr 
sqlservr
  Version 14.0.3008.27
  Build ID 5fb3474a5f63ad2f4b7eddadad44a086839721f18a66c5fb5d7cfcce25c0f539
  Build Type release
  Git Version 693be7c
  Built at Sat Nov 18 04:54:59 GMT 2017

PAL
  Build ID a984d7631c4f1eb55ae1c77cfb51a09b905528d4e05e728a6343af04e744d96f
  Build Type release
  Git Version 2fe1654
  Built at Sat Nov 18 04:54:06 GMT 2017

Packages
  system.sfp                    6.2.9200.2,2fe1654c9,
  system.common.sfp             10.0.15063.540
  system.certificates.sfp       6.2.9200.2,2fe1654c9,
  system.netfx.sfp              4.6.1590.0
  secforwarderxplat.sfp         14.0.3008.27
  sqlservr.sfp                  14.0.3008.27
```

Answer (score 0):

You can either connect to the mssql server via:

- Use [SQL Server Management Studio](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/ssms/sql-server-management-studio-ssms) remotly from Windows (note: remote connection needs to be enabled);
- Use [sqlcmd](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/tools/sqlcmd-utility) in linux terminal with the command `sqlcmd -S localhost -U SA -P '<YourPassword>'`
- Use [mssql-cli](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/tools/mssql-cli) with `mssql-cli -S localhost -U SA -P '<YourPassword>'` (see [docs](https://github.com/dbcli/mssql-cli/blob/master/doc/usage_guide.md)).

and then run the following sql query to check YOUR VERSION:

```
select @@version
go
```

Example:

[image]